# Binding event not firing when service called from a different view model

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have a parent `UIViewController`, this has it's own view model declared as so

```
lazy var chatService: ChatService = {
    let chatService = ChatService()
    return chatService
}()

lazy var viewModel: ChatControllerViewModel = {
    let viewModel = ChatControllerViewModel(chatService: chatService)
    return viewModel
}()
```

This view controller has a `UITableView` declared as so

```
   lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        return tableView
    }()
```

Inside `viewDidLoad` I have a binding as such

```
    viewModel.reloadData = { [weak self] in
        self?.insertNewMessage()
    }
```

That triggers the following method

```
fileprivate func insertNewMessage() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: viewModel.history.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

This works perfectly. I also have a child view controller, which is of type `UICollectionViewController` declared as

```
lazy var chatQuestionsCollectionView: ChatQuestionsController = {
    let layout = SnappingCollectionViewLayout()
    let cv = ChatQuestionsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return cv
}()
```

This `UICollectionViewController` has its own view model, set up in the same way as above.

This all works well to a point;

My `ChatControllerViewModel` calls the ChatService and requests the latest messages, these are then pushed from the ChatService to my View Model as such

**ChatService**

```
var pushResponse: ((_ response: ChatMessage) -> Void)?
```

**ChatControllerViewModel**

```
   init(chatService: ChatService = ChatService()) {
        self.chatService = chatService

        chatService.pushResponse = { [weak self] response in
            self?.chatHistory.append(response)
        }
    }
```

This pushes a new message to my `UITableView` and then reloads the data, displaying the message.

However, my child view controller, then `UICollectionView` also talks to the `ChatService` - it contains a series of horizontal scrollable buttons that trigger a response.

When pressing a button, I can see through logging, my chat service is called, logic runs as expected, however at the point the chat service calls `var pushResponse: ((_ response: ChatMessage) -> Void)?` my view controller does not update.

I suspect this is because my UICollectionView is talking to a different instance of the `ChatService` that does not have that binding established.

Does this sound plausible? If so, what would be the correct way to negate this issue? I considered using a delegate pattern, but am unsure what I should be delegating and to where.

To give some context on the layout:

I have a table view presenting chat messages vertically.
At the bottom of the view, I have a collection view, presenting buttons that scroll horizontally.

Pressing these buttons call the chat service, which should in turn trigger a binding with the table view view model, which should reload the table view with new data.

Comment: After appending in your chat history are you reloading your collection view?

Comment: No, however the chat history is displayed in the tableview, which I believe the binding between the view model and view should call.

Comment: But how does your view model knows that i have to load the view once the chat history is mutated? i think you need to call reloadData method of your view model here once you are appending in the chatHistory

Comment: Sorry yes, I missed that snippet off, that is happening already

Comment: This process works, when my table view view model talks to the chat service, it’s once my collection view view model talks to it, that the view is not updated.

Comment: have you kept a breakpoint and checked that the control is coming inside the pushResponse callback? or your chathisotry is getting appending properly?

Comment: Yes, everything works perfect until the point my collection view view model calls the chat service and the chat service calls the binding method with the table view view model, to reload the data. The binding event does not trigger anything in my view model. Only when my table view view model calls the chat service does this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `ChatService` in your collection view which does not have the binding setup.

If you do not want to use a Singleton, I would create a instance of it in your parent most component and pass it down via [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).